# Use Backup Exec configuration 2010 R3 file on 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backupexec

I'm looking to upgrade my backup solution from Symantec Backup Exec 2010 R3 (Which i believe is the same version as 13) to Backup Exec 2012. Now, it's pretty easy to open BEutility and use the "Copy media server configuration"-function in 2010 R3, but I have not found any answers as to whether this file can be imported flawlessly into 2012 or not. It would save loads of time if it's doable.

Since I HAVE TO remove the 2010 installation before installing 2012, it's not possible to just test it. I need to know before I go through with it.

Anyone who's tried the same?

PS: Running Windows Server Standard 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use the "Apply Copied media server configuration" function in 2012 from a 2010 .cfg file, since 2012 handles the jobs differently. Instead you have to upgrade-install 2012 on top of 2010 so that the software can split the jobs as it sees necessary.